# detect all versions of IE when visiting webpage

Tags: jquery

I am having huge issues in making my website work in multiple browsers. I like to detect when a user is using any IE version.

does anyone have coding to alert me when it detects IE?

Gordon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) property:

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    alert('IE !');
}
```

Comment: This only works for jQuery versions before 1.9  (http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed)

Answer (score 1):

```
if( /msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) ) {
    // omg it's an internet explorer
}
```

This is the real quick&dirty solution. Anyway you should do feature detection instead of browser detection. For instance, if you need a `JSON` parser, go for

```
if( 'JSON' in window ) {}
```

This would be the correct solution. To check for a browser (maybe even the version also) is not realiable.

Comment: I think MSIE started identifying itself as a version of Mozilla at some point. http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/

Comment: @Jake: `MSIE` is contained in any of those strings.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to detect IE? Feature detection, rather than browser sniffing, is the preferred way to deal with things whenever possible. (I don't think it's *always* possible, but it's *almost* always possible.) jQuery's [`jQuery.support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) offers a number of these and the linked page for it offers great links to feature detection in general. Or, as Darin says, you can look at `$.browser`, but that's really a last resort.

If you post questions with the actual problems you're having cross-browser, odds are pretty high people can help you address them in a way that doesn't rely on browser sniffing.

Comment: @Jake: As I said: "I don't think it's *always* possible, but it's *almost* always possible."

Comment: @Gordon: Yes. That's part of why you want to detect *features* rather than *browsers*. Example: When hooking up event handlers using DOM2-style attachment functions, because IE supported `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`, you sometimes see people checking for IE via the user-agent string or whatever and then using `attachEvent` if they think the browser is IE. Then IE9 comes along, which supports `addEventListener`, and that code keeps using `attachEvent` unnecessarily. *Feature* detection would mean looking for `addEventListener`, not IE. Seamlessly works when IE9 comes out.

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside value judgments of browser versus feature detection, you can also use IE conditional comments:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isIE = false;
</script>
<![if IE]> <!--- only runs in IE --->
    <script type="text/javascript">isIE = true;</script>
<![endif]>
```

Comment: Beware the performance implications of conditional comments (on IE): http://www.phpied.com/conditional-comments-block-downloads/

Comment: That's a good point. A workaround is to have an empty conditional comment at the top of your document; this solves the blocking issue. But of course we're just piling ugliness on ugliness...

Answer (score 0):

$.browser.msie is not supported in latest version of jquery you can either add jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js or use following jquery function... for IE it also gives you version ...

call currentBrowser().browser to detect browser and currentBrowser().version for IE version .........

```
function currentBrowser() {

$.returnVal = "";

var browserUserAgent = navigator.userAgent;

if (browserUserAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {

    $.returnVal = { browser: "Firefox" };
}

else if (browserUserAgent.indexOf("Chrome") > -1) {

    $.returnVal = { browser: "Chrome" };
}

else if (browserUserAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1) {

    $.returnVal = { browser: "Safari" };
}

else if (browserUserAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1) {

    var splitUserAgent = browserUserAgent.split(";");

    for (var val in splitUserAgent) {

        if (splitUserAgent[val].match("MSIE")) {

            var IEVersion = parseInt(splitUserAgent[val].substr(5, splitUserAgent[val].length));
        }
    }

    $.returnVal = { browser: "IE", version: IEVersion };
}

else if (browserUserAgent.indexOf("Opera") > -1) {

    $.returnVal = { browser: "Opera" };
}

else {
    $.returnVal =
     { browser: "other" };
}

return $.returnVal;
}
```